# Non-TLD wildcard in SAN for self-signed ssl cert

Tags: ssl, openssl

I followed the excellent write up [how-do-you-sign-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority/21340898#21340898) to create my own self-signed cert. I set the SAN for *.pro and *.pro.example.com

If I hit the web02.pro.example.com all works fine.

When I hit web02.pro it doesn't work:

curl --cacert cacert.pem https://web02.pro/version.html
curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'web02.pro'

web02.pro and web02.pro.example.com both resolve to the same machine, and that machine is set up to answer to both names.

The cert I generated shows:

```
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:   
            DNS:*.pro, DNS:*.pro.example.com
```

Is there anything limit to using a not read TLD for a self-signed cert?

Answer (score 3):

Many clients not only check that the hostname against all names in the certificate, but also only allow wildcards which are not too permissive. This means that wildcards like `*.pro.example.com` or `*.example.com` are considered valid while wildcards which only specify the top-level domain like `*.pro` are considered invalid and will not be included in the validation process.

This reason for this is that below a top-level domain you will usually find lots of domains with different owners. A wildcard certificate for `*.pro` would thus include domains from different owners which should better not be possible.